# JTable editor keep old values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, tablecelleditor

Ok, I notice a problem with my editor in `JTable`. The scenario looks like this :

- I edit a cell and enter a valid value, lets say I enter 42
- I double click on an other cell (which can be empty or not)
- The cell now contain 42, I can edit this value but as I double click on the cell 42 is in the cell.

I suspect my editor because when I use `DefaultCellEditor` there is no problem. Here is its declaration :

```
public class GlobalEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
public GlobalEditor(JTable table, JTextField jtf) {
    super(jtf);
    /*
     * Setting font, background/foreground color, center alignement
     */
}

public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    String value = ((JTextField) getComponent()).getText();
    if (!value.equals("")) {
        if (value.length() > 10) {
            ((JComponent) getComponent()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.stopCellEditing();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    JTextField ec = (JTextField) editorComponent;
    if(value != null && value+"" != "---")
        ec.setText(""+value);
    if (isSelected) {
        ec.selectAll();
    }

    return editorComponent;
}
```

}

This line `this.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new GlobalEditor(this, new JTextField()));` sets my editor in my `JTable` constructor.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this worked :

```
JTextField ec = (JTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
```

Instead of (also return `ec` instead of `editorComponent`) :

```
JTextField ec = (JTextField) editorComponent;
```

In the `getTableCellEditorComponent` method.

Any **explanation** is welcomed !

Answer (score -1):

You should override getCellEditorValue method

```
  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return ((JTextField) getComponent()).getText();
  }
```

Also no need to initialize GlobalEditor with JTable

Comment: Done now. Thanks for the tips @Igor, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean in your edit : " initialize GlobalEditor with JTable" ? I don't see any constructor for `GlobalEditor` parent that takes a `JTable`

Comment: public GlobalEditor(JTextField jtf) {
        super(jtf);
     }